# Running mocha from vscode works, but an error window pops up shortly after, why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mocha.js

VSCode config:

```
    {
        "name": "tests current file",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 6868,
        "windows": {
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\mocha\\bin\\_mocha",
          "args": [
              "--timeout", "999999",
              "--opts", "tests\\mocha.opts",
              "${file}"
          ],
        },
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
```

The tests run fine, but an error window appears like 2 seconds after. It reads:

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6868).

[image]

How do I make sure that error doesn't appear?